# Anyone used "Print to PDF" option in Transform designer ??? (Bottomline)

Tags: transform, designer

Anyone used "Print to PDF" option in Transform designer ??? (Bottomline)

The PDF output obtained from this is having very big file size. I want to reduce it. Anybody knows about this??
By reducing the DPI, I'm getting the output Pdf with lower size. But this will reduce the clarity of the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use "Print to PDF" object I am afraid that this is your only option.

What is working good for me when I want to reduce the size of the PDF is to use - "Advanced printer" Object and then you need to choose "Microsoft print to PDF" in Use Specific printer option. Normally this reduces for me around 40% of the PDF size without the need to sacrifice the quality.